# Is a python dict comprehension always "last wins" if there are duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, dictionary-comprehension

If I create a python dictionary with a dict comprehension, but there are duplicate keys, am I guaranteed that the last item will be the one that ends up in the final dictionary? It's not clear to me from looking at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/?

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in [(1,100),(2,200),(3,300),(1,111)]}
new_dict[1] #is this guaranteed to be 111, rather than 100?
```

Comment: Yes, the last value will be added. if you did it explicitly outside the comprehension `new_dict[1]  = 111` would you expect 100 or 111? Just because it is in a comprehension does not make the order of inserts different.

Comment: It will always be the last value, it is like overwriting the previous one!

Comment: The last value that the iterable gives the comprehension will be the one that is written last.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The last value for a key wins. The best documentation I can find for this is in the [Python 3 language reference, section 6.2.7](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> A dict comprehension, in contrast to list and set comprehensions, needs two expressions separated with a colon followed by the usual “for” and “if” clauses. When the comprehension is run, the resulting key and value elements are inserted in the new dictionary **in the order they are produced**.

That documentation also explicitly states that the last item wins for comma-separated key-value pairs (`{1: 1, 1: 2}`) and for dictionary unpacking (`{**{1: 1}, **{1: 2}}`):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, ... you can specify the same key multiple times in the key/datum list, and the final dictionary’s value for that key will be the last one given.
>
> A double asterisk `**` denotes *dictionary unpacking*. Its operand must be a mapping. Each mapping item is added to the new dictionary. Later values replace values already set by earlier key/datum pairs and earlier dictionary unpackings.

Note that [as wim points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437015/), the first version of a key wins if there are equal but distinct keys:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in [(1, 1), (1.0, 2.0)]}
{1: 2.0}
```

Here, the final dict has the key from `(1, 1)`, but the value from `(1.0, 2.0)`.

Answer (score 20):

> am I guaranteed that the last item will the the one that ends up in the final dictionary?

Not exactly...

In case of duplicate keys, the **first key** is preserved, and the **last value** is preserved. The resulting **item** (key, value) may not have been present in any of the original pairs in the first place.

```
>>> {1.0: 1, 1: 1.0}
{1.0: 1.0}
```

This behaviour somewhat documented under [Dictionary displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) (emphasis mine):

> This means that you can specify the same key multiple times in the key/datum list, and the **final dictionary’s value** for that key will be the **last one** given.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean something like

```
{key: val for (key, val) in pairs}
```

where `pairs` is an ordered collection (eg, list or tuple) of 2-element lists or tuples then yes, the comprehension will take the collection in order and the last value will "win".

Note that if pairs is a set of pairs, then there is no "last item", so the outcome is not predictable. 
EXAMPLE:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> pairs = [("a", i) for i in range(n)]
>>> {key:val for (key, val) in pairs}
{'a': 9}
>>> {key:val for (key, val) in set(pairs)}
{'a': 2}
```